# How to authenticate with Tableau Server API via python?

Tags: python, authentication, tableau-api

I'd like to authenticate with [Tableau Server API](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Python/html/classtableausdk_1_1_server_1_1_server_a_p_i.html#a89706cb18cfc57028a1335f9b4e5002b), so that I can publish extracts.

However, I'm having issues with basic authentication

```
from tableausdk.Server import *
from tableausdk import *

ServerAPI.initialize()
serverConnection = ServerConnection()
serverConnection.connect('http://online.tableau.com', 'email_address', 'password','https://10ay.online.tableau.com/#/site/example/views/site/Sheet1')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2217, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/API/tableau_api.py", line 144, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/API/tableau_api.py", line 140, in main
    print login_try_rest()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/API/tableau_api.py", line 136, in login_try_rest
    t.signin()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/tableau_rest_api/tableau_rest_api.py", line 602, in signin
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/tableau_rest_api/tableau_rest_api.py", line 2796, in request_from_api
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/tableau_rest_api/tableau_rest_api.py", line 2773, in __make_request
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm positive my username and password are correct, and I've tried the following as well:

```
    ServerAPI.initialize()
    print ServerConnection().connect('http://online.tableau.com', 'username', 'password','')
```

I've also tried the following using the Tableau Rest API, which is outlined in [this documentation](https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_rest_api)

```
t = TableauRestApi('http://online.tableau.com', 'username', 'password')
logger = Logger(u"log_file.txt")
t.enable_logging(logger)
t.signin()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2217, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/API/tableau_api.py", line 154, in <module>
    t.signin()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/tableau_rest_api/tableau_rest_api.py", line 602, in signin
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/tableau_rest_api/tableau_rest_api.py", line 2796, in request_from_api
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/tableau_rest_api/tableau_rest_api.py", line 2773, in __make_request
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Whats your tableau version?

Comment: I utilize Tableau Online and Tableau Desktop (Version 9.2). When I login into the online version, this is the domain as well: https://10ay.online.tableau.com. I'm not sure if this is what you mean by tableau version

Comment: Can you connect to the tableau server, i mean your server not the tableau online.?

Comment: I dont have my own server. We just use Tableau Online, which is a different product from Tableau Server I believe.